# PHP when to use filter_var instead of built in php functions

Tags: php, filter-var

I noticed there are many things you can do with the PHP [`filter_var`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php) function which can also be done with other function.

For example, the filters `FILTER_VALIDATE_REGEXP`, `FILTER_SANITIZE_ENCODED` and many more also have their respective dedicated functions in PHP.

When should I use `filter_var` and when should I use the PHP functions? What are the advantages and disadvantages?

Comment: use php_filter anytime you can, it's build-in (little faster and you are sure you use the right validation), if you can't find what you need, then use a custom one.

Comment: I wasn't talking about custom functions, since built in function will always be faster. I was talking about filters which already have a native php function alternative.

Comment: I understand, but if you use a preg_match you will have to customize the regexp - I should have said, customized regexp with preg_match sorry about the confusion

Comment: but with FILTER_VALIDATE_REGEXP you should also customize the regexp. Of course using regexp to validate an email address is a lot slower than FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL!

Comment: @Tiddo: FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL uses a regex internally. https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/filter/logical_filters.c#L499

Comment: But probably already compiled and thus faster.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The advantage of the [`filter`](http://php.net/filter) extension is that you have everything in one place.

But you are right, it doesn't provide much novel features. You could do most of the stuff with existing functions, in particular [`preg_replace`](http://php.net/preg_replace) or [`preg_match`](http://php.net/preg_match) instead of `FILTER_VALIDATE_REGEXP`. Or typecasting, and using the normal [`htmlspecialchars`](http://php.net/htmlspecialchars) instead of the filter option.

There is however [`filter_var_array`](http://php.net/filter_var_array), where one benefit becomes apparent. You can filter loads of variables per config. And you can predefine a list of filters to apply **all at once**:

```
$_POST = filter_var_array($_POST, array(
    "text" => FILTER_SANITIZE_ENCODED,
    "id" => FILTER_VALIDATE_INT,
    "title" => FILTER_SANITIZE_ENCODED,
));
```

I admit that's basically a triggered magic_quotes example, but you get the picture. Unification.

Answer (score 6):

To this day I haven't found a faster (or better) way of removing special characters from a string than using filter_var

```
filter_var($string, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING, FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_HIGH)
```

Like many things in PHP, there are multiple ways of doing them.  filter_var is convenient.

Comment: Does this hold for every filter_var function which has another built-in equivalent? Or is this only for this filter?

Comment: Yes, well for string related versions.  Take a look here, you'll see FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_HIGH applies to some

Comment: Upvoted to compensate for the downvote. I think this is a valid and often overlooked solution.

Answer (score 1):

I just run a microtime benchmark side by side 50 times against `preg_match` in an `if` statement and `filter_var_array` validating the exact same reset data, here are the microtime results:

```
filter_var_array
microtime: 0.000834226608276

preg_match
microtime: 0.000180006027222
```

`filter_var_array` looks pretty but is 4 to 8 times slower than `preg_match` so if you have a high traffic website and prefer speedy code I would recommend `preg_match`.

However if you like nice clean code and don't really care how it runs then use `filter_var_array` which may be more manageable for applying easy filters on many forms requests and inputs.

But this kind of ease can also be achieved by writing a `preg_match` function for different scenarios such as email or alphanumeric but keep in mind `preg_match` security when writing the regex for example:

http://blog.php-security.org/archives/76-Holes-in-most-preg_match-filters.html

I would like to see a memory usage compassion on both also.

Hope this helps

Comment: Premature optimization is the root of..., you know.